# How can I make the angle theta bigger such that it covers more space?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is what I have currently:
it doesn't fit the amount of space, so what can I do to make it larger/fit?

Here is the code below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,patterns,angles,quotes}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',scale=1.75]
    % save length of g-vector and theta to macros
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gvec}{1.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{30}
    % calculate lengths of vector components
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gcos}{\Gvec*cos(\myAngle)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Gsin}{\Gvec*sin(\myAngle)}

    \coordinate (centro) at (0,0);
    \draw[dashed,gray,-] (centro) -- ++ (0,-3.5) node (mary) [black,below]{$ $};
    \draw[thick] (centro) -- ++(270+\myAngle:3) coordinate (bob);
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=2.3] {angle = mary--centro--bob};
    \draw [blue, -stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gcos cm!(centro)$);
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!-\Gcos cm!(centro)$)
      coordinate (gcos)
      node[midway,above right] {$mg\cos\theta$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ($(bob)!\Gsin cm!90:(centro)$)
      coordinate (gsin)
      node[midway,above left] {$mg\sin\theta$};
    \draw [-stealth] (bob) -- ++(0,-\Gvec)
      coordinate (g)
      node[near end,left] {$mg$};
    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = g--bob--gcos};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Set [`angle radius`](https://tikz.dev/library-angle#tikz/angle:radius) to a bigger value than the default `5mm`.

Comment: The code is missing ```\usepackage{tikz}```, ```\begin``` and ```\end{document}```. The question is not clear to me, but perhaps what you want is to modify the angle in  ```\pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{30}```.